# Copying password protected docx from jar to Documents

Tags: java, jar, password-protection, docx

I am attempting to copy a password protected docx from jar to Documents. I have currently tried to use getResource(). While it gets the correct path and the docx exists in the jar (I unpacked it to double check) I am still getting a file not found exception and it is reporting the specified path doesn't exist. Is there an alternative or something I may be missing? Any help would be great and just ask if you have any question :)

```
String genericPath = Klass.class.getResource(Klass.getSimpleName() + ".class").toString();
genericPath = genericPath.substring(10, genericPath.length()-37);
//How to go back to base directory of jar
File fileSrc = new File(genericPath + "/configFiles/"serverConfig.docx");
//Location of docx
File fileDest = new File("C:/Users/Me/Documents");

FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(fileSrc, fileDest);
```

Comment: You can copy a password protected document. You just can't view or edit it.

Comment: Does the directory exist that you are saving it to?

Comment: @Rogue Yes, I make sure it exists before saving it there

Comment: @AnubianNoob I know, the ability to copy it to a new location is all I really need to do.

Comment: That's what I'm saying... It's not because the file is password protected; that's not your problem.

Comment: can you paste some code and exception. using FileInputStream or getResourceAsStream?

Comment: @andy I just posted an example on how I attempting to copy the file.

Comment: so can you success if you copying a file which is no password protected?

Comment: @andy I can't access anything as I continue to test this which is very odd. Can you not use File if it is located in a jar? I just attempted .Exists() on current class and it for some reason is returning false?

Comment: File cannot read files in jar, you can using InputStream is = Klass.class.getResourceAsStream("/configFiles/serverConfig.docx");then read the stream and write to the new file.

Comment: Use a different jar for your testcase, one that contains no protected files and whose contents you understand.  If you get that working, then figure out why the difference.

Comment: Will you be able to read it if the docx is password protected? Sorry, if my understanding of reading a stream is limited.